# Inserting CSV with blank value into SQL table with BIGINT column

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert, bigint

I am attempting to insert a number of CSV files into a SQL Server (2016) table. One of the CSV files contains a blank value, for example:

```
ID, VALUE, DATE
235425, 34, '2018-05-08'
234567, , '2018-05-08'
233456, 67, '2018-05-08'
```

The process I am running attempts to insert this value into a BIGINT column, and the blank value appears to be breaking the process, resulting in the following error message:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint

Can anyone shed some light on best steps to debug/resolve this problem?

Comment: You can first insert into a staging table, with a nvarchar column, and move it on from there.

Comment: parse each line and replace each empty column with 0 before insertion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, you should first insert all data as is into a staging table. This has two benefits:

1. No data is lost in bringing from file into SQL server
2. You can then operate on staging tables using SQL queries which are far faster than any external processes.

you can also use queries with TRY_PARSE or TRY_CONVERT or [`TRY_CAST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) functions to insert data like below

```
INSERT INTO Tbl
SELECT ID,
Value= TRY_CAST(Value as bigint),
Date= TRY_CAST(Date as date)
FROM stagingTbl
```